# Outlook 2013 Add-in Tutorial for beginners

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have spent the better part of a day piecing together bits of information on how to get into the Object model of developing Add-ins, and only found marginal coverage of the fundamentals, none of which goes into any real detail about the core functionality.

I am attempting to develop an add-in to read an email as it is received and fire off a process based on content level within that email.

I would rather figure out how to do this myself, so any recommendations on where to start in programming for Office (other than MSDN), or 'ground-up' tutorials would be much appreciated. Alternatively direction on the proper coding solution would also be appreciated. (i am developing this in c#)

Comment: Off topic! That's the wrong place to ask for tutorials etc. Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest starting from the [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) article. Then see the [How do I... (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863719.aspx) section in MSDN.

Also you may find a [HowTo articles](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/author/eugene-astafiev/) helpful.

It looks like you need to handle the NewMailEx event. In that case you will find the following articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)